# Which of const and let is better to use when declaring array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Let's say I have an array of users.

```
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Cena John' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Marcus Ignacious' }
];
```

Yes, the `users` variable is not re-assignable. But what if I add some data to it?

```
users.push({id: 3, name: 'Kanye South'});
```

I know that the value of `users` didn't change, only the values inside it.

What I'm wondering is whether there's any convention for preferring let over const when it comes to arrays.

One of my colleagues said that I should use `let` since the value is updated.

Which one is preferable to use?

Comment: If you don't need to overwrite `users`, `const` is the way to go

Comment: i prefer let if is mutable, like a push to one array, and const for inmutable values const pi = 3,14; but i've not found convention laws for this.

Comment: Neither is "preferable". Just use a common convention, developed together with your colleagues, on whether you use `const` to mean that a value is immutable (and not just the variable).

Answer (score 5):

you should use `let` if

```
let a = 5
a = 10
```

or

```
let a = [12,3]
a = ['s',23]
```

But you should better use `const` if

```
const a = [12,3]
a.push('s')
```

in this case `a` doesn't changing - it was a link to the array and it is still a link to the initial array

Answer (score 4):

> One of my colleagues said that I should use let since the value is
>   updated.
>
> Which one is preferable to use? Any help would be much appreciated.

A good practice is using `const` first for every variable declaration. Whenever you feel that you want to **reassign** that variable to another value, then it's time for changing to `let`.

In your case, using `const` is totally fine.